# How to have a texture not be affected by lights, shadows, etc.?

Tags: three.js

I'm mapping a few textures onto a geometry, however, I'd one of the textures to not be affected by lights, etc. What's the best way of achieving this?

Comment: Maybe use [`MeshBasicMaterial`](http://threejs.org/docs/api/materials/MeshBasicMaterial.html)?

Comment: Have an example? Not sure how to apply many textures to one mesh, with only one not being affected

Comment: http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Materials/MultiMaterial

Answer (score 1):

if you use [MeshStandardMaterial](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Materials/MeshStandardMaterial), you can use the emissiveMap. it is not affected by any lights.